# Selecting an atrribute when performing grouping by another attribute

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table named `Pokemon` that has info about some pokemons.

```
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--+
|    name    | type  | weight | color  |  |
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--+
| bulbasaur  | grass |     10 | green  |  |
| squirtle   | water |      7 | blue   |  |
| charmander | fire  |      8 | orange |  |
| cyndaquil  | fire  |      4 | black  |  |
| staryu     | water |     12 | orange |  |
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--+
```

I would like to group this table by color and select the name of each pokemon
belonging to each color group.

Namely I want 4 groups :

1. green
2. blue
3. orange
4. black

and the names of each pokemon in each group:

1. bulbasaur
2. squirtle
3. charmander,staryu
4. cyndaquil

I have tried using the GROUP BY clause in SQL like so:

```
SELECT name
FROM POKEMON
GROUP BY color
```

but that does not work since the GROUP BY clause insists that the column attribute in SELECT must either be involved in the GROUP BY or have an aggregation function act on it.

Since it is my third day coding in SQL I have not found a solution to this problem yet.

Thank you in advance for your time trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want string aggregation. In Postgres, you would phrase this as:

```
select color, string_agg(name, ',') as names
from pokemon
group by color
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. That is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also select the color, such as :

```
SELECT name, color
FROM POKEMON
GROUP BY name, color
```

Comment: Sadly that does not work since it produces this error : 

[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dfd5d7/13)

`ERROR: column "pokemon.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 8`

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: By the way, do you really need to group by? Since each pokemon name is unique, you don't need an agregation clause. This is usually used when you need to average something. In my proposed answer, the group by clause is rather useless...

Comment: Following your edit, i'd say GMB's answer is what you need. Disregard mine.